# Name of embedded resource

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

In C#, the default behaviour of embedded resource name is like this:

```
<default namespace.><extended namespace.><filename>
```

Without changing the default namespace of the project, can I control the name of embedded resource?

Comment: According to some other sources the filename is truncated after the first period, and spaces are replaced with underscores and path separators (for nested folders in your "extended namespace") are replaced with periods. It's very annoying this mangling can't be turned off.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The way to do this is quite simple, but you will have to edit the Visual Studio Project (csproj or vbproj) file in a text editor. See [this MSDN blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/msbuild/how-to-change-the-name-of-embedded-resources).

Here is the relevant XML snippet:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedResource Include="bar.resx">
      <LogicalName>notfoo.bar.resources</LogicalName>
  </EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 8):

If you're still having a bit of a hard time after trying @JustinDearing's answer, try this:

1. set the verbosity of MSBuild to 'Detailed' in your V.S. options:
   [image: Visual Studio > Tools > Options dialog]
2. Build your project
3. Copy the output from the 'Build' log pane, paste into a text editor, search for 'manifest'
   [image]

Comment: I use Ildasm or dotPeek to find the name of embedded resources inside assemblies.