# Swashbuckle custom asset not found

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle

I added to *SwaggerConfig.cs* this string

```
c.CustomAsset("index", thisAssembly, "Table.Web.CustomContent.index.html");
```

...than I run the application, go to *swagger* docs and get error:

> An error has occurred.
>   
>   Embedded resource not found - Table.Web.CustomContent.index.html
>   
>   Swashbuckle.SwaggerUi.AssetNotFound

The *build action* property of the *index.html* was set to *embedded resource*

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: I am assuming that the this-> Table.Web.CustomContent.index.html corresponds to the correct path of the index.html file. I mean it should be a combinatino of namespace and the path of the file

Comment: @SillyJohn _"Table.Web"_ is project name in this case, _"CustomContent"_ is directory that I've created

Comment: That should be the namespace of the project. See the documentation in Github - https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle#injecting-custom-content

Comment: @SillyJohn cool! It worked

Comment: Good to know that..:)

Answer (score 7):

I struggled with this for a while today in a ASP.NET C# project and finally resolved it by cobbling together a few different resources.

First (as noted in the Swagger comments), the item must be marked as an **Embedded Resource** by right-clicking the item in the solution explorer and going to Properties, and selecting Embedded Resource from the Build Action dropdown.

Second, the logical name can be tricky to identify. In my case, a dash in a directory name was being converted to an underscore once embedded, leading to lots of hair-pulling (hair_pulling?). The easiest way to get the true logical path is to get it from the Build Output window.

1. Go to Tools => Options
2. Expand the Projects and Solutions sidebar item and click Build and Run
3. Set the MSBuild Output to Detailed.
4. Clean the solution and rebuild, opening the Output window if necessary.

The output log should unambiguously state the true logical name of the file with a line like...

`Resource file 'swagger-ui\SwaggerUiStyle.css' gets manifest resource name 'MySolutionName.swagger_ui.SwaggerUiStyle.css'`

([credit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44721536/4822220) to @bkwdesign for his excellent explanation on this part)

Comment: I had the same issue. My project name included a -, which changes to a _

Comment: Solved my problem, i was searching for something like this Api.Toto.index.html but it was actualy Stuf.Api.toto.index.html