# Can I attach a Word document to a Windows Application?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-word

I have a Windows Forms application for which I have written an extensive manual in Word with helpful pictures. Is there a way to include the .docx in the .exe so that users can click a button in the application to open to manual in Word?

Comment: Sure, you just need to include it in your output directory and open it from there using a process.start command with shell execute.

Comment: @rory.ap is correct, though I recommend a PDF rather than a Word document.  There's a better chance your users will be able to read it.  I, for instance, don't have a copy of Word on any computer I use.

Comment: Add the file to your resources. You can then reference it from there and it will be included when you create a setup project.

Comment: I agree with adv12. Convert it to a PDF.

Comment: @adv12 That's pretty good advice, but it's for an internal tool at my company so I can be confident Word is installed.

Comment: @Zath, if I add it to resources, will it then be under source control? And could I edit it in Word and save it while it is under source control?

Comment: Yes, it would be under source control and yes you can edit it. BUT, any user that installs the app will not have the latest version. May want to look into WCF.

Comment: Thanks. I'm pretty far down the road in this technology so I may just have to package it with the .exe instead of switching tech.

Comment: for internal tool seems easier to put it in shared folder and link to it. Otherwise you can add it to the Visual Studio Project and cange its [Copy to Output Directory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/0c6xyb66) Property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of "attach" I think you mean "embed".

And yes, you can, by storing it as an Embedded Resource.

There are three ways to embed resources in .NET Win32 programs:

- As a Win32 PE Resource. This is not easily used from within .NET code as there's no built-in API for them (so you'll need P/Invoke (`DllImport`)), but means that other programs can acces the resources.
- As an Embedded Resource Stream stored directly, this is accessed using the `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream()` API in the .NET Framework. This is the fastest way (as it's exposed as a `Stream` instead of a byte array, so it isn't loaded into memory unnecessarily).
- As a `Byte[]` inside a .NET `.resx`/`.resources` resource. This is suboptimal because the file is wrapped in another abstraction and exposed as a `Byte[]` instead of a `Stream`, but you can more easily manage the files in Visual Studio.

I recommend the `GetManifestResourceStream` method, so do this:

1. In your project, include the Word document in the Project (Solution Explorer > Show All Files > (your doc, right-click) > Include File
2. Select the file then open Properties and under "Build Action" choose "Embedded Resource"
3. Note that the project-root relative folder-path will be translated into a dot-separated name prefix for your resource, so if the file is `My Project\Documents\Readme.doc` then the resource name will be `Documents.Readme.doc`. [You can override this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605514/name-of-embedded-resource), but you will need to edit your `.csproj` file directly (using the `<LogicalName>` element).
4. Then build, and your `*.doc` file will be embedded.

In your code, do this:

```
// use a GUID generator to create a new GUID in a string literal (do not run `Guid.NewGuid()` or `new Guid()` at runtime!) to create a globally unique filename so you don't accidentally overwrite other files
const String _myFileName = "12345.doc"; 

static void ShellInvokeReadmeDocument() {

    String destFileName = Path.Combine( Path.GetTempPath(), _myFileName );
    if( !File.Exists( destFileName ) ) {

        Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(); // change as appropriate
        using( Stream source = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Documents.Readme.doc") )
        using( Stream destination = File.OpenWrite( destFileName ) ) {

            source.CopyTo( destination );
        }
    }

    Process.Start( destFileName );
}
```

Note that I don't recommend using a `.doc` or `.docx` file as it is not guaranteed that the user will have Word installed (unless you know your customers will have it).

Note that WordPad in Windows does not necessarily have the ability to open `.doc` files! On Windows 7 and later WordPad only opens `.docx` files and does not support all formatting options, only a small subset, and WordPad on Windows Vista and earlier does not support opening `.docx` files.

If you want to maximize compatibility, I recommend using `.pdf` files if you want to preserve printed-page formatting and layout, or an `.rtf` file.

If this file is meant to constitute a Help or Documentation file, then you should use a `.chm` file instead, which is structured and fully supported by all Windows versions from Windows 98 onwards - you can also integrate `.chm` files with WinForms with the "What's this?" button and tooltips (`.chm` files are not to be confused with `.hlp` files which are not supported by Windows after Windows Vista).

Comment: I've tried this and although it works, I can't update the file that has become an "Embedded Resource".  Is there something special that needs to be done in order to update the docx, or pdf?