# How to change the generated ManifestResourceName for Embedded Resources

Tags: c#, deployment, msbuild, embedded-resource

In a C# project, the generated resource name for an `Embedded Resource` by default undergoes some mangling to make the resulting name a namespaced valid language identifier.

For example `Foo/Bar/123.txt` becomes `{Default Namespace}.Foo.Bar._123.txt` and I have to load it with `asm.GetManifestResourceStream("Yuck.Foo.Bar._123.txt")`.

I would much rather have my resources retain their relative path such as `Foo/Bar/123.txt` to better simulate a virtual file system and so I can load them such as `asm.GetManifestResourceStream("Foo/Bar/123.txt")`.

Now I know that .Net does not place restrictions on resource names, so it seems feasible.

But how do I get the build engine to generate sensible path names for me?

Comment: Related post - [Name of embedded resource](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3605514/465053)

Comment: @RBT thanks for digging that up

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the `.csproj` file, the `Embedded Resources` are defined as `<EmbeddedResource>` items.

These have metadata named `<LogicalName>` which allows overwriting the name of the resource from whatever would otherwise be generated.

For example:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedResource Include="Foo\Bar\123.txt">
    <LogicalName>Foo\Bar\123.txt</LogicalName>
  </EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>
```

would generate a resource which could be loaded using `asm.GetManifestResourceStream("Foo\Bar\123.txt")`

To do this for all of our embedded resources, we can add a renaming task to the .csproj file which runs before the default names are generated and explicitly assigns names of our choosing:

```
<Target Name="ModifyEmbeddedResourceNames" BeforeTargets="CreateManifestResourceNames">
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource>
      <LogicalName>%(EmbeddedResource.Identity)</LogicalName>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

With this we get resources named by their `Identity`.

Comment: How can I do the automatic method for resources in part of the app? I have resources I want to preserve folder structure for in `/Content` and it's a WPF app so I need resources in the `/UI` folder to remain as dots.

Comment: I ended up splitting the content files to a separate project and only having the resources in that project stored with slashes. This is working perfectly and keeps WPF happy and is probably a good idea for separation anyway.

Comment: @Sellorio You could have also used MSBuild's Choose/When construct https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-conditional-constructs?view=vs-2022 I am not sure about the exact syntax, as it can be finicky

Answer (score 1):

If you're using "new-style" (aka "SDK-style") `.csproj` files then you can take advantage [of new behaviour in MSBuild that allows properties on MSBuild Items to be specified as attributes instead of as child elements](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/pull/1093).

So instead of doing this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <!-- etc -- >

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Foo/Bar/123.txt">
      <LogicalName>FooBar123Txt</LogicalName>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

You can now do this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <!-- etc -- >

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Foo/Bar/123.txt" LogicalName="FooBar123Txt" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remark: Not this question, but sometimes usefull.
If you just want to change default namespace for many files
in autogenerated resource names you need set RootNamespace property:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <RootNamespace>OtherThanProjectNamespace</RootNamespace>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Foo\**" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Result:

asm.GetManifestResourceStream("OtherThanProjectNamespace.Foo.Bar.123.txt").