# How to get view file content as plain string

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razorengine, asp.net5

ASP.NET Core 5 MVC application uses razor engine from https://github.com/adoconnection/RazorEngineCore to render views as strings at runtime.

How to get view `~/Views/Checkout/Order.cshtml` content as string?

I tried

```
ReadTemplate("~/Views/Checkout/Order.cshtml")
```

but it throws an error. Application may deployed as single file or as separate files.

```
string ReadTemplate(string filename)
{
    var stream = GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(filename);

    if (stream == null)
        throw new ApplicationException(filename + " view not found");

    StreamReader reader = new(stream);
    string template = reader.ReadToEnd();
    reader.Close();
    return template;
}
```

Comment: Think about what happens if your Razor views are precompiled - there's no way to get the raw source of `.cshtml` files if they aren't included in the deployment. They aren't included as assembly resources either.

Comment: How to force view to be included as assembly resource ? It is used only by application as string content to render. It is not regular view, not used to create html page. Is it sufficient to set build action as `embedded resource`. Which path should used to get this resource ?

Comment: If it's not a Razor file, why does it have a `.cshtml` file extension?

Comment: It is razor file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to get view ~/Views/Checkout/Order.cshtml content as string?

You could try to create a ViewRenderService with the following code:

```
public interface IViewRenderService
{
    Task<string> RenderToString(string viewName, object model);
}
public class ViewRenderService : IViewRenderService
{
    private readonly IRazorViewEngine _razorViewEngine;
    private readonly ITempDataProvider _tempDataProvider;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;

    public ViewRenderService(IRazorViewEngine razorViewEngine,
                             ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider,
                             IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
    {
        _razorViewEngine = razorViewEngine;
        _tempDataProvider = tempDataProvider;
        _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
    }

    public async Task<string> RenderToString(string viewName, object model)
    {
        var actionContext = new ActionContext(_contextAccessor.HttpContext, _contextAccessor.HttpContext.GetRouteData(), new ActionDescriptor());

        await using var sw = new StringWriter();
        var viewResult = FindView(actionContext, viewName);

        if (viewResult == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException($"{viewName} does not match any available view");
        }

        var viewDictionary = new ViewDataDictionary(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new ModelStateDictionary())
        {
            Model = model
        };

        var viewContext = new ViewContext(
            actionContext,
            viewResult,
            viewDictionary,
            new TempDataDictionary(actionContext.HttpContext, _tempDataProvider),
            sw,
            new HtmlHelperOptions()
        );

        await viewResult.RenderAsync(viewContext);
        return sw.ToString();
    }

    private IView FindView(ActionContext actionContext, string viewName)
    {
        var getViewResult = _razorViewEngine.GetView(executingFilePath: null, viewPath: viewName, isMainPage: true);
        if (getViewResult.Success)
        {
            return getViewResult.View;
        }

        var findViewResult = _razorViewEngine.FindView(actionContext, viewName, isMainPage: true);
        if (findViewResult.Success)
        {
            return findViewResult.View;
        }

        var searchedLocations = getViewResult.SearchedLocations.Concat(findViewResult.SearchedLocations);
        var errorMessage = string.Join(
            Environment.NewLine,
            new[] { $"Unable to find view '{viewName}'. The following locations were searched:" }.Concat(searchedLocations));

        throw new InvalidOperationException(errorMessage);
    }
}
```

Add the following references in the above service:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;
```

Then, register the ViewRenderService in the Startup.ConfigureServices method:

```
services.AddScoped<IViewRenderService, ViewRenderService>();
```

After that, you could use this service to render view page as a string:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{ 
    private readonly IViewRenderService _viewRenderService;
    public HomeController(IViewRenderService viewRenderService)
    {  
        _viewRenderService = viewRenderService;
    }
     
    public async Task<IActionResult> CategoryIndex()
    {  
       //The model will be transferred to the View page.
        var stulist = new List<Student>() { new Student() { StudentName = "AA" }, new Student() { StudentName = "BB" } };

        var result =  _viewRenderService.RenderToString("Views/Student/Index.cshtml", stulist).Result;

        return View();
    }
```

The result like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Great code. How to pass view content as string so that view can read from database  ? There should be two possibilites: pass view as string or by name like in your code

Comment: Yes, you are right. In my opinion, I prefer to store the view name in the database, then, after getting data from Database, I could also choose which view will be used to render the records(according to the view name).

Comment: View content (not name) is stored in database. How to use this content to render view ? It should compiled at runtime. Why `.Result` is used instead of `await` ?

Comment: Hi @Andrus, After getting the view content (html resource), you could use [`@Html.Raw()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.ihtmlhelper.raw?view=aspnetcore-5.0) method to render the html content. "Why .Result is used instead of await", I'm using it to debug and it can help to see the html content more clearly.

Comment: View content from database contains `@inject` and other razor command.How to force `@Html.Raw` to compile and render view from database ?. Will `.Result` usage cause error if async methods are used in view since execution is not suspended?

Comment: In your controller, after getting the view content (html string), you could transfer the data to view via ViewData or ViewBag, then, use `Html.Raw()` method in the view page. screenshot like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17ilE.png).

Comment: `Index.html` file does not exists in project. Its content exists in database only. How to render view in this case ?

Comment: Do you mean you are using JQuery Ajax to call the action method, and get the html content from the database? If that is the case, in the action method, you could return the html string, and  in the Ajax success function, after getting the html string from the response, try to use [append() method](https://api.jquery.com/append/) to add the html content in the current page.

Comment: View is order tempate in Razor syntax which can changed by every customer and is stored in database. It should be rendered to string and sent in email body as order confirmation. How to pass order razor template as string to your method. It should compile it and after that use your code to render,

Answer (score 0):

In your comment reply you wrote this:

> How to force view to be included as assembly resource ? It is used only by application as string content to render. It is not regular view, not used to create html page. Is it sufficient to set build action as Embedded Resource. Which path should used to get this resource?

You can either [infer the resource stream name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/resources/manifest-file-names) yourself, or [you can manually specify a name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605514/name-of-embedded-resource) by directly editing your `.csproj` file to specify a `<LogicalName>` (I don't know why this element isn't exposed in the Properties window, it really should be). The latter option is better, as the name will remain constant when moving files around).