# How to provide a relative path using System.IO.File inside a hosted ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api, system.io.file

I have an ASP.NET Web API that is hosted on Azure as an app service. I have workflows that automatically call an endpoint once a month. However, these triggers have been failing due to the following error:

```
"body": "Could not find a part of the path 'C:\\home\\site\\The-Food-Works-WebAPI\\Assets\\loyalty-template.html'."
```

At this endpoint, I am attempting to access a file (also in this web api project) through the following code:

```
string body = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("..\\The-Food-Works-WebAPI\\Assets\\loyalty-template.html");
```

If I had to run the endpoint locally, everything would work just as intended. I believe the relative path is fine, but due to the way it is being accessed (through System.IO.File), it expects the file to be saved locally?

EDITS: (Using Embedded Resource):

```
var resourceName = "..//The-Food-Works-WebAPI//Assets//loyalty-template.html";
       string body;
       using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
           {
                TextReader tr = new StreamReader(stream);
                body = tr.ReadToEnd();
           }
```

Azure now gives the following error:

```
"body": "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'stream')"
```

Comment: As an alternative, have you considered using Embedded Resources instead? (`Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream`?) That way you can always be sure that the content will exist because it will be embedded in your assembly.

Comment: Azure App Services use `D:\home\site\etc` instead of `C:\home\site` btw. I think you assumed the wrong drive-letter.

Comment: Is this ASP.NET Core - or ASP.NET 4.xx? They have different ways of getting the absolute path to the application deployment directory.

Comment: @Dai This is ASP.NET Core. I am not sure on how one would change the drive-letter? I will have a look at Embedded Resources as well. Thank you for the quick suggestion!

Comment: You can't change the drive-letter of Azure App Services, it's always `D:\`, so I'm curious why `ReadAllText` resolved `..` to `C:\home` instead of `D:\home` - because it works for me at my end.

Comment: @Dai I have attempted to make use of an embedded resource. I have set the `loyalty-template.html` to an embedded resource (Properties > Build Action > Embedded Resource). And then using a method found online I have attempted to set the body variable to the text content of this file. However, Azure now says `"body": "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'stream')"` Would you mind having a look at the edits made to the question to see what I could have done wrong?

Comment: Your `resourceName` is wrong. You'll need to hand-edit your `.csproj` to set the `<LogicalName>` for the resource and then use _that_ for the `resourceName` (which you should store as a `const`). See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605514/name-of-embedded-resource/3605851

Comment: Also, you need to dispose of your `StreamReader` instance. Always use a `using` block.

Comment: @Dai Thank you so much for putting me in the right direction and providing additional tips. I just have one last question, would a logical name be necessary? Or could I simply just include the item group without a logical name?

Comment: I **strongly recommend** always setting an explicit `<LogicalName>`, otherwise MSBuild generates a resource-name based on the path of the file relative to the `.csproj`, which means it will change (quite unpredictably so!) if you ever move files around your file-system. I'm surprised and disappointed that Microsoft chose to hide `<LogicalName>` instead of exposing it in the Properties window. (The alternative is to use `.resx`/`.resources` files, but they're kinda old-fashioned and don't add any value - I think of it more as a favour to VB.NET users than something we should use today)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Dai, I am converting the above comments as an answer so that will help other community members:

So after changing your resource name and  editing your
`.csproj`  to set the `<LogicalName>` for the resource and then use *that* for the `resourceName` and also after disposing the `StreamReader` instance and by using a `using` block hopefully resolved  the issue.

And It is recommended that always setting an explicit `<LogicalName>`, otherwise MSBuild generates a resource-name based on the path of the file relative to the `.csproj`, which means it will change (quite unpredictably so!) if you ever move files around your file-system.