# absolute sound path to work in other machines

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, audio

I am using the following code:

```
SoundPlayer soundPlay = new SoundPlayer(@"C:\more\more\Assets\Sounds\menuHoover.mp3");
soundPlay.Play();
```

when clicking in a button to reproduce a sound, but I have to use the absolute path to works, since I am not the only one doing working on this project, I have to use a poth comon to others too. How can I use the relative path to make this work?

I have tried diferent paths, but none seems to work. Only the absolute one.

Comment: Assets\Sounds\menuHoover.mp3 is relative path only. I didn't understand your question

Comment: Exatly, and it does not work

Comment: Use relative path. For example, you can create a folder in your project then put the file in the folder

Comment: you need to first check what is the current path? `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` then you can check your mp3 file path

Comment: I know what is the directory of the file, the problem is if someone else program on it, any of the sounds will work, it will have to adapt all paths to his own ones.

Comment: The assets are already inside the project directory

Comment: "other machines" your compiled app is sent to are not going to have a project directory

Comment: But I am not alone working in this project, they need to be able to use them also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may include the file as Embedded Resource into your executable. Then there is no need to distrubute the file separately.

To access the sound resource, use `Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("<Namespace>.menuHoover.mp3");` and initialize the SoundPlayer as `new SoundPlayer(stream);`

What to put in `<Namespace>`? Have a look in the project properties at "Default namespace". Suppose this is `A.B.C`. This would be the Namespace if you add the mp3 file at the root directory of the project. If you add it to a sub-directory, say `X\Y\Z`, the namespace would be `A.B.C.X.Y.Z` (special rules apply if the directory name contains characters not allowed in an identifier). See also [Name of embedded resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605514/name-of-embedded-resource)

Comment: @Maneneco I hope you'll take a second look at this answer. It not only solves the problem of team development but _also_ is very deployment-friendly when the time comes to publish your app and install it other devices.

Comment: Its not working, what I am suppose to put in namespace?

Comment: @Maneneco Added some information to my answer.

Comment: So something like this Stream hoover = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Assets.Sounds.menuHoover.mp3");

Comment: And then  SoundPlayer soundhover = new SoundPlayer(hoover)
                 soundhover.Play();

Comment: The only output I get is the swindows sound sytem, the one that you normally get when something is wrong.

Comment: Yes I know it is my code, all answers here work independently, I have tested them all. My problem is applying it to my project. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have several options one is to add the location of the assets to a configuration file such as app.config

For example you could add to your app.config file:

```
<configuration>
 <appSettings>
  <add key="AssetPath" value="C:\\more\\more\\Assets\\Sounds\\"/>
 </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Then in your code you could use something like:

```
string assetPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AssetPath"];
SoundPlayer soundPlay = new SoundPlayer(Path.Combine(assetPath,"menuHoover.mp3");
soundPlay.Play();
```

Another would be to build a path dynamically based on where your application was executed from and then build a relative path from that:

```
string appDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
string assetPath = Path.Combine(appDirectory,"Assets","Sounds");
SoundPlayer soundPlay = new SoundPlayer(Path.Combine(assetPath,"menuHoover.mp3");
soundPlay.Play();
```

Comment: Please use Path.Combine https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine

Comment: Well, its not the solution I was looking for, but it solvs a lot of work

Comment: @Maneneco What solution were you looking for?

Comment: A way that I i had not to change that path for every person working on the code. Besides ConfigurationManager its not working.

Comment: It does not find the path like that, I have tried both ways